# when dropdown selected their details to be shown in popup how to do that?

Tags: php

Here is my scenario,

IN my page i have a charity dropdown box,when user select any one of the dropdown ,the charity details should be shown in popup box,how to do that???

Answer (score 1):

You should use jQuery to handle the event "onchange" and then complete the other inputs with data retrieved maybe after an Ajax request ?

Here is some kind of code you could use :

**HTML Select input :**

```
<select id="charity">
<option id="idtest">test</option>
<option id="idtest2">test2</option>
<option id="idtest3">test3</option>
<option id="idtest4">test4</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript with jQuery :**

```
$(function() {
$("#charity").change(function() {
var selectedOption ID = $("#charity option:selected").attr("id");
// Here is your ajax with jQuery too. Use the var "selectedOption" to know which option is selected
});
});
```

Comment: You should add a _ in "selectedOption ID" !